# Hide button and show hidden p-tag on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want a button with two functions when clicked; the button should vanish and a hidden p-tag (display: none;) should reveal itself.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button.call-us").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $("p.phonenumber").show();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p class="phonenumber" style="display: none;">0271 12222</p><button class="call-us">Call us</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The code above works flawlessly with [w3schools testing tool](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_basic).

But when I try to do it live at my website, nothing happends.

**My .js-file** (button-phone.js) **contains the following**:

```
(function($)
{
    $("button.call-us").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $("p.phonenumber").show();
    });
});
(jQuery);
```

**It's included in the code, far down, just before the body tag closes**

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/button/js/button-phone.js?ver=1.0.4'></script>
```

**I have imported the jQuery library in my head-tag**

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.2'></script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wpb_wrapper">
<p class="phonenumber">555 000 000</p>
<p><button class="call-us">Call us</button></p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.phonenumber {
display: none;
}
```

The p-tag is hidden, but nothing happends when I click the button.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried using your browser debugger to see if your Javascript files are being loaded? Also is there any chance of a jsFiddle example? Nice name by the way

Comment: It looks like your js files are 404 not found: http://www.website.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.2 and http://website.com/wp-content/plugins/button/js/button-phone.js?ver=1.0.4

Comment: @apaul34208 you think he owns website.com :D

Comment: @shehary Nope, I think he's linking to resources that aren't available.

Comment: @apaul34208 I am hiding my website, I can promise you that the JS is 200 OK! Contains the same I declare in the question.

Comment: @LiuKang You might want to use example.com for that. website.com is an actual site while example.com is reserved for use in examples.

Comment: @apaul34208 I see, sorry - I will do that from now on!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still a typo question... You have an extra closure, remove it and it will work:

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/0skdth48/)

```js
(function($) {
  $("button.call-us").click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $("p.phonenumber").show();
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.phonenumber {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wpb_wrapper">
  <p class="phonenumber">555 000 000</p>
  <p>
    <button class="call-us">Call us</button>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Solved. Worked great. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Change your jQuery to this and it will work

```
(function($){
    $(".call-us").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $(".phonenumber").show();
    });
});
})(jQuery);
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/05zw7qjo/3/)

Suggestion, Try to bind jQuery with unique ids or class, don't use common class which you may use on other part of website

HTML

```
<div class="wpb_wrapper">
    <p class="phonenumber" id="PhoneNo">555 000 000</p>
    <p><button class="call-us" id="Call">Call us</button></p>
</div>
```

And jQuery

```
(function($){
    $("#Call").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $("#PhoneNo").show();
    });
});
})(jQuery);
```

And CSS

```
#PhoneNo {
    display: none;
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/46554mob/1/)

Comment: Sometimes using a class is advisable, id's aren't strictly necessary: http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/46554mob/2/

Comment: Agree with you but i suggest becoz OP is using class which he may be use anyother part of website and lets say he already define `.phonenumber {
display: none;
}` and if he repeat same HTML in footer or contact page he wonders why its not showing. so suggest assing unique ids or unique class when binding with jQuery, answer edited as per suggestion

Comment: In this case I am actually using two buttons at the same page. One in the header and one in the sidebar. So, I changed from classes to ID's.

Answer (score 1):

Try editing your button-phone.js to the below -

```js
(function($)
{
    $("button.call-us").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $("p.phonenumber").show();
    });
})(jQuery);
```